# How to access a public method in a private static inner class from another class?

Tags: java

How to access the public function of private static inner class in some other class Suppose there is a class structure like below :-

```
public class Outer{

  private static Inner {
    public void func() {    
    }
  }
}
```

And there is another class :-

```
class UseFunc {    
  // I have to use the func() here     
}
```

If I use like this it will give error : - create object of Inner like `Outer.Inner oi = new Outer.Inner();`
 `access oi.func()`  //as Inner is private class

Comment: Did you test above code what output it is giving Stackoverflow user can answer a question when you tried something and you got some issue

Comment: What is the point of making a class private and method as public ?

Comment: Yeah I tested this and it gives compile time error that cannot access as Inner is private .

Comment: Same is my doubt ... That what is the use of having public method in private inner class and how to use it outside

Comment: No, you can't.That is what private mean. [Know about access modifiers](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html)

Comment: I know private means we cannot access it outside but my point is what is the sense of making public method inside private inner class . Because I saw such kind of implementation and was confused by this use of public method.

Comment: @pooja - if you're interested in concepts, then ask directly for them: "What are the uses of declaring a public method in a private inner class?" (and delete this question) Then you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a very bad (I mean, really terrible) implementation but it works:

```
public class Outer
{

    private static class Inner
    {
        public void func()
        {
        }
    }

    public void encapsulatedFunc()
    {
        new Inner().func();

    }

}


class UseFunc
{    
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       new Outer().encapsulatedFunc();
   }
}
```

I can only imagine that code being used for educational purpose as a "What not to do" example.